# Swift: Protocol for enum doesn't work

Tags: swift, enums, ios8, protocols

Part of the protocol definition that I need for an enum, is to hold a dictionary with "self" as a key. So this was my first attempt:

```
protocol Orderable {                               // line 1
    class var first: Self { get }
    class var last: Self { get }  
    class var strings: [Self : String] { get }     // line 4
}

enum Item : Int, Orderable {
   case ItemA = 0, ItemB, ItemC
   static let last : Item = Item.ItemC

   var name : String { return Item.strings[self]! }

   static let strings: [Item : String] = [ 
        .Item1: "item no. 1", .Item2 : "item no. 2", .Item3: "Item no. 3"
   ]
}

println ("last item is: \(Item.last.name)")    // ==> "last item is: item no. 3"
```

That failed on line 4 with the error:

**type 'Self' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'**

To solve that, I tried to inherit Orderable from Hashable as follows:

```
protocol Orderable : Hashable { ...  }
```

However Playground crashes when I try that.

Is that the correct solution to the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the Playground crashing isn't so much with your `Orderable` protocol, but more with your `Item` enum. It's true that `Orderable` will need to implement `Hashable` for it to work, but the problems you're seeing in your Playground are more due to `Item` not implementing `Orderable` correctly. Playgrounds are still fairly unstable when code isn't written just right, so it's not too surprising to me that it's crashing on you.

So, to work around the compiler bugs in Xcode 6.0, you need to do the following:

***Note:** If you're using Xcode 6.1, see update.*

In your `Orderable` protocol, you've defined `first`, `last`, and `strings` as read-only computed properties, but you've defined them as read-write stored properties in your `Item` enum. Also, you've neglected to implement your `first` property altogether.

Instead of defining `last`, for example, as:

```
static let last : Item = Item.ItemC
```

It needs to be defined as a `var` with a expression that `return`s `Item.ItemC`:

```
static var last : Item { return Item.ItemC }
```

The same basic idea can be applied to `first` and `strings`.

Also, in your `strings` property, you've used `.Item1`, `.Item2`, and `.Item3`, instead of `.ItemA`, `.ItemB`, and `.ItemC`.

So, if we fix all that we get:

```
protocol Orderable: Hashable {
    class var first: Self { get }
    class var last: Self { get }
    class var strings: [Self : String] { get }
}

enum Item : Int, Orderable {
    case ItemA = 0, ItemB, ItemC

    static var first: Item { return .ItemA }
    static var last : Item { return .ItemC }
    static var strings: [Item: String] {
        return [
            .ItemA: "item no. 1", .ItemB : "item no. 2", .ItemC: "Item no. 3"
        ]
    }

    var name : String { return Item.strings[self]! }
}
```

Which works nicely with this quick test:

```
println("last item is: \(Item.last.name)")
println("first item is: \(Item.first.name)")
println("item B is \(Item.strings[Item.ItemB])")
```

Outputs:

> last item is: Item no. 3
>
> first item is: item no. 1
>
> item B is Optional("item no. 2")

---

**Update:** As @David pointed out in the comments, what I said above regarding implementing the properties of the `Orderable` protocol in `Item` only seems to be an issue in Xcode 6.0.  In Xcode 6.1, it's perfectly reasonable to implement the properties the way you were originally. In the Xcode 6.1 playground, this works fine:

```
protocol Orderable: Hashable {
    class var first: Self { get }
    class var last: Self { get }
    class var strings: [Self : String] { get }
}

enum Item : Int, Orderable {
    case ItemA = 0, ItemB, ItemC

    static var first: Item = .ItemA
    static var last : Item = .ItemC
    static var strings: [Item: String] = [
        .ItemA: "item no. 1", .ItemB : "item no. 2", .ItemC: "Item no. 3"
    ]

    var name : String { return Item.strings[self]! }
}
```

Comment: His primary problem is that he doesn't declare Orderable as an extension of Hashable, which you've fixed as a side effect of fixing a lot of other issues he has.  The definition `class var first: Self {get}` in the protocol merely says that the protocol requires that there must be a get method.  There aren't any restrictions on the implementation, you can, in fact implement it with both get and set methods, although the 6.0 compiler seems to have issues with it.  On the 6.1 compiler it seems fine.

Comment: @David They do say in the question that they're trying to declare `Orderable` as `Hashable` and I reiterated that in my answer so I think that's covered. My point was mainly that it isn't working (in their case the Playground is crashing) because of the other issues in their code. Re: restrictions on property implementations, I didn't realize that, thanks. I was using the 6.0 compiler at the time, but I've since installed the 6.1 GM and I see you're correct. I'll update the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Yeah, I was just trying to point out that you're working around a compiler bug, it should be fine the way it was written. I took a lot of stuff out, including the Hashable, stripped it down to the minimum of a variable declaration and definition and it still crashed on 6.0. The glories of working with a language (and implementation) that are still a long ways from production-ready.

Comment: BTW, it's also acceptable to define first, last, etc as `var` and have them be mutable as well.  Although actually assigning to it crashes the playground...

Comment: Oops, I actually meant to make those `var`s in my edit; thanks for pointing that out. I also tweaked my original answer to point out that this is partly to work around a compiler bug. Maybe one of these days we won't have to do so many workarounds in Swift...

Comment: Thank you for your answers. It looks like using a "static let" for a protocol definition of "class var" crashes Playground. It does seem to work fine when used not in the Playground, though.

Comment: Another mistake I made, which was not obvious right away, was using Self. It made the protocol generic. What I really needed was to use "Orderable", as in: "class var first: Orderable { get }".

Answer (score 0):

```
protocol ExampleProtocol {
    var simpleDescription: String { get }
    mutating func adjust()
}

enum SimpleEnum : ExampleProtocol {
    case enumMember(String)
        var simpleDescription: String {
            get {
                switch self {
                    case let .enumMember(descript):
                        return descript
                }
            }
    }
    mutating func adjust () {
        switch self {
            case let .enumMember(desc):
                self = .enumMember(desc + " (adjusted)")
        }
    }
}

var c = SimpleEnum.enumMember("A simple enum.")
var csimpleDescription = c.simpleDescription
c.adjust()
var dsimpleDescription = c.simpleDescription
```

Comment: It is considered bad style by some to post uncommented code with no textual description or explanation - i.e. this answer was flagged low quality